# Double dimensional array to single dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am just doing an experiment to put values in double dimensional array to a single dimensional array. Below is my code and result:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int p[1][1];
int arrayA[4];

for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
    {
        p[i][j] = i+j;
    }
}
int *a = &(p[0][0]);
for(int k=0;k<4;k++)
{
    arrayA[k] = *a;
    cout << "*a:  " << *a << endl ;
    cout << "array[k] :" << arrayA[k] << endl;
    cout << "a:   " << a << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------" << endl;
    a++;
}
system("PAUSE");    
    }
```

and the result is:
[image]

But I have no idea why it missed the value of p[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwKlh.jpg)[0], which value should be 1. But instead, I got a weird number where it is from. Because this is weird to me that I can put the last number in the double dimensional array to the single dimensional array but not the number before.

So I hope somebody can tell me what happen to me code or my method of thinking. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't post a screenshot, post the actual text output.  It's easier to read, and to copy-and-paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This results in an out of bounds on array `p`:

```
int p[1][1];
int arrayA[4];

for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
    {
        p[i][j] = i+j;
    }
}
```

Indexes on arrays run from `0` to `N - 1`, where `N` is the size of the array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you wrote:

```
int p[1][1];
```

Remember that in C, and in C++, the number on elements for dimensions is the true number that you mean the vector or matrix to have. However, their indexes run from 0 to n-1 (where n is the number you wrote). So your declaration of p should be:

```
int p[2][2];
```

instead.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `int p[1][1]` but I think you meant `int p[2][2]`.